# Getting net.serenitybdd.core.exceptions.SerenityManagedException: Could not initialize class

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, serenity-bdd, jbehave

I am getting en error while running our scripts in chrome headless through gitlab pipelines

net.serenitybdd.core.exceptions.SerenityManagedException: Could not initialize class

what does it mean could you guys please help to resolve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Actually i am trying to run my scripts in gitlab runners chrome headlesss mode. my code working fine in local machine but while running same through gitlab pipelines its showing error as  net.serenitybdd.core.exceptions.SerenityManagedException: Could not initialize class